# Any way for FileReader to only read the third line of a txt file?

Tags: java, authentication, passwords, filereader

I am making a login system, using a encrypter when you signup to 
    store a crypted password, that will then be decrypted when the login is 
    made, and will finally be compared to the one used to login to see if they 
    match.
    The way I am storing the credentials is:

- Username on the 1st line
- Email on the 2nd
- Password on the 3rd

How do I make the file reader only read the 3rd line?
Language is Java and this is all being done in JFrame Form.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: So... where are you stuck at the moment?

Comment: How are you going to know where the 3rd line starts if you haven't read the previous two?

Comment: If I were you, I'd store the information on a single line, separated using a predefined character e.g. : , # or any other character that is not present ou your entry.

Comment: Share your code man.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to allocate a number of bytes for each section. For example, if you allocate 50 characters for your username, 50 characters for the email, and 50 characters for the password, you can do the following:

```
File f = ...;
FileReader reader = new FileReader(f);
fin.skip(100);
char[] chars = new char[50];
int numCharsRead = fin.read(chars); //confirm numCharsRead is 50
```

Comment: You can also use RandomAccessFile's seek() - which is basically the same as skip().

Answer (score 1):

> How do I make the file reader only read the 3rd line?

You can't.  Basically, the reader needs to read all lines, and *ignore* the lines that it isn't interested in.

Hint:  Look at `BufferedReader.readLine()`; see @noscreename's answer.

(The reason that a `FileReader` cannot do this is that you don't know how long each line will be until you have read it completely.  Since using `Reader.skip(...)` or `RandomAccessFile.seek(...)` require you to know how many bytes / characters to skip over, they are not applicable here.)

---

However, what you are trying to do here is a bad idea.

1. Sequentially reading account "records" from a file of each time you want to authenticate a user is not going to scale.  The more accounts you have, the longer it will take to log in.
2. Storing passwords in a file in clear is bad security practice.  Storing passwords encrypted in a file is almost as bad.  Instead, you should store seeded password hashes; see the Wikipedia page on [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)).

Answer (score 0):

```
String file = "your_file_path";
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));

String password = "";
boolean end = false;
try {
    while (true) {
        reader.readLine();
        reader.readLine();
        password = reader.readLine();
        // do stuff with password
    }
} catch (EOFException e) {
   // end of file reached. will break the loop
} catch (IOException e) {
   // handle exceptions
} finally {
    reader.close();
}
```